# Homestead Update from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 Issue with 502 Gateway Error Related to Failed Restart of php7.0-fpm.service

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, homestead

I updated the homestead virtual box from `v1.0.0` to `v1.0.1` for a per project installation for a Laravel 5.3 application, and now whenever I `vagrant up` I get this error:

```
Running: script: Restarting Nginx
Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service not found.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Which is the cause of the 502 Bad Gateway error when attempting to run the app.

I tried some of the usual suspects:

1. installed the latest virtualbox and vagrant versions
2. removed the box and re-downloaded
3. provisioned
4. destroyed the box including files
5. downgraded to `v1.0.0` (now have this error on this version as well)
6. checked composer version of `laravel/homestead` which was `^3.0`, and attempted an update using composer, but no update available
7. checked `laravel/homestead` on github saw `v3.1.0` so updated `composer.json` manually and updated (downgraded back to `v3.0.0` since that didn't work and didn't know the implications of the update)

So I'm completely blocked now, and technically my setup is now back to what it was prior to updating to `v1.0.1` so it should be working?  Anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the answer in the github closed issue queue: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/392

Short version is update laravel/homestead up to `v4.0.0` in composer.json for per project installations. So `"laravel/homestead": ^4.0.0`

**Update**

Apparently you can lock yourself into PHP 7.0 if you're not ready for PHP 7.1 using version v3.1.0 according to this post:
https://www.joeferguson.me/laravel-homestead-4-0-and-box-1-0/